# MySQL saying that column is ambiguous

Tags: mysql

I need to do a query on the same field on a MySQL table but with different parameters.  This is my query.  The issue that comes up is that MySQL is saying that users_name is ambiguous.

```
SELECT projects_id, 
projects_users_id,projects_companies_id,projects_name,
projects_description,project_registered_date,
projects_users_id_register,
users.users_name as userInCharge,companies.companies_name as company,
users.users_name as user_register FROM projects 
LEFT JOIN users as userInCharge ON (users_id = projects_users_id) 
LEFT JOIN users as register ON (users_id=projects_users_id_register)
LEFT JOIN companies ON (companies_id = projects_companies_id) ORDER BY projects_id DESC
```

My goal is to get the ID of both the person in charge of the project and the person who registered the project.  How do I do this?

Comment: You are repeating users.users_name selection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ambiguity is arising because of these `LEFT JOIN` clauses:

```
LEFT JOIN users as userInCharge ON (users_id = projects_users_id) 
LEFT JOIN users as register ON (users_id=projects_users_id_register)
```

You need to specify where `users_id` is coming from (yes - I know they're from the same table, but SQL is a bit slow sometimes) Try:

```
LEFT JOIN users as userInCharge ON (userInCharge.users_id = projects_users_id) 
LEFT JOIN users as register ON (register.users_id=projects_users_id_register)
```

Comment: Also in the select users.users_name is used twice without aliases

Comment: They are not from "the same place" at all.  One of them is from one subset of users and the other is from a totally different subset of users.  Without disambiguation, SQL is quite right in refusing to answer the question, since joining the table twice makes it 2 places, not 1.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Where would we be without the pedants?

Answer (score 0):

Use the table alias and not users.users_name.

And also in the joins.

Answer (score 0):

You JOIN with `users` table as `userInCharge` and `register` so use these names when You specify columns

```
userInCharge.users_name as userInCharge
register.users_name as user_register
```

instead of

```
users.users_name as userInCharge
users.users_name as user_register
```